# Converting odds ratios to probabilities.

Tags: probability

Let's say I have an outcome variable 1/0 ( recovered/dead) and two predictor variables, - one is continues (age) and one is binary ( condition x - yes (1) / no (0)). The odds ratio for age variable is 1.26. How do I convert it to a probability? For the condition x, the odds ratio is equal to 0.23. How to interpret it? The reference level for the outcome variable is 0 - dead.

Edit:
I am making a binomial regression model with various response variables, some of them are factorial, some are continuous. The response variable is binary and it takes two values (0 - recovered, 1 - dead). Two predictors for an example - age and condition x. Age is a continuous variable and condition x is a binary variable(1 - yes, 0 - no). I calculated odds ratio for these variables. I got odds ratio for age 1.26, I'd like to know how to interpret it. Can it be interpreted as for every y aged person that dies there are 1.26 patients aged (y+1) that die? Let's say that there are 40 years difference between patients. Then 1.26*40 = 48.2. So for every y aged patient that dies, there are 48.2 patients aged (y+40) that die? Can I determine the probability that 40 year old person dies knowing just the odds ratio?

How to translate it to probability? Following what Lulu said: I get the probability of 126/226 = 63/113. But I don't understand what this probability means.

For the second variable: The odds ratio is 0.23. Does that mean, that for every person that doesn't have the condition x (0) that survives, there are 0.23 patients with condition x( 1) that survive? Following what Lulu said: $\frac{23}{123} \approx 0.16$. Is this probability of recovering for a patient with a condition x?

[image: Here is the model, it's in different language, but the age variable is called Vecums]

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean by reference and outcome variable.  If an event has odds of $a:b$ then the associated probability is $\frac a{a+b}$.  Thus even odds, $1:1$, correspond to a success probability of $\frac 12$.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: What does “odds ratio” mean for “age”, if it’s a continuous random variable?

Comment: Can you edit your post for clarity?  It's really not clear what you are asking.  In my prior comment, I gave you the standard conversion from odds to probability but I have no idea if that's what you were asking about.   Presumably, it wasn't.  Can you clarify?

Comment: @lulu, I think the OP is asking about “odds ratio”, which is the ratio of two odds. For example, if the odds of death given condition is 2 (probability is 2/3), and the odds of death given “not condition” is 1/3 (probability is 1/4), then the odds ratio is $2/(1/3)=6$

Comment: Do you have a logistic model?  If so, could you state it explicitly?  Any constant/intercept will affect the probabilities

Comment: @Joe  Well...If so, I don't understand what probability is desired. In the case where the variable is independent of the condition, the ratio you mention is always $1$, yes?  So there's no chance of backing out a probability from that.  But, really, the OP ought to clarify.

Comment: @lulu I edited my post. Yes, I am talking about logistic regression. If probabilities are impossible to obtain, I'd just like to be sure whether I am interpreting the odds ratio correctly.

Comment: Thank you for the edit, but I don't understand what, say, the $1.26$ means.  How did you compute it?   Are you making age into a binary variable?  Maybe by declaring that everyone is either "old" or "young"...but even then, I don't understand what you are computing.  I think if you write out exactly what computation you are doing it will help a lot.

Comment: @lulu I am using glm() function and then odds.ratio() in R. So, ok, I cannot compute odds.ratio for continuous variable... The coefficient for age variable is equal to 1.26. So, how do I interpret it, if the response variable is binary? Also, does my interpretation for the second variable is correct, aside from the probability part?

Comment: So, you have two pools, A,B.  Pool $A$ has $a_1$ people with a given characteristic and $a_2$ people who do not.  pool $B$ has $b_1, b_2$ respectively.  Then I believe the ratio you are computing is $\frac {a_1}{b_1}\times \frac {b_2}{a_2}$.   There is no way to back a probability out of that, for the reason I mentioned earlier.

Comment: @lulu Ok, but is my interpretation of variables correct. if condition x variable coefficient ( odds. ratio) is 0.23, does that mean, that for every person who does not have a condition x, that recovers, there are 0.23x patients, who have the condition x, that recover? The same with age. The coefficient is 1.26. How do I interpret it in this case?

Comment: I have no idea what you are doing with the continuous variable.  For the binary variable, then yes.  You are, effectively normalizing the odds which means that you are setting $a_2=b_2=1$.  Thus you are computing the ratio $\frac {a_1}{b_1}$, i.e. the ratio of the people with the desired characteristic.

Comment: @lulu If, the binary regression coefficient for age is 1.26, how do I interpret it? ( the exponent is already been taken).

Comment: What's a "binary regression coefficient"?   You have a model here, unspecified as far as I can see.  Your Generalized Linear Regression has found the best parameters for it.  I assume that the $1.26$ is one of those parameters.  Either you or the system has specified the functional form...what is that form?

Comment: @lulu I am not sure if I understand you correctly, but I use logistic regression. family = "binomial". The coefficients you see is in log form, so I took odds.ratio() ( which exponentiates these parameters).

Comment: I'm not familiar with the statistical package you are using...I'm more used to specifying the model myself.  I expect that someone familiar with this specific package could be of more use.

Comment: The [Cross Validiated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) website is specifically for statistics question.  I expect someone there will know exactly what this particular system returns.

Comment: @lulu Here I found an approximate explanation of the coefficients for this model: For a one unit increase in gpa, the log odds of being admitted to graduate school increases by 0.804. So, in my case, for every unit increase in age, a person is 1.26 times likely to die?

Comment: Well, but it's a non-linear regression.  So the derivative should not be constant.  That's why I would look at the explicit functional form.

Comment: Related https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/86351/interpretation-of-rs-output-for-binomial-regression